# Server Manager “target namespace does not exist”

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We are on Windows 2012 Server R2. We are getting an "Online - Data retrieval failures occurred" message when we go to Server Manager. So we examined the Applications and Service Logs and came across this error:

> Invoke method error. Server: localhost, Namespace: root\microsoft\windows\servermanager, Class: MSFT_ServerManagerTasks, Method: GetServerInventory, Error: The target namespace does not exist.

Has anybody gotten this error? What steps did you take to resolve it?